# Loading an animation in a reflection cube using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made a reflection cube and I am trying to put an animated model inside. But something happen in my function render and I can not see anything.

I am making my first steps using javascript and playing with three.js. If you can help me would be amazing.

```
    //var scene, camera, etc

        var container, loader;
        var camera, scene, projector, renderer;
        var controls;
        var mesh, mixer;
        var pointLight;
        var mouseX = 0;
        var mouseY = 0;
        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
        var height = 300; // of camera frustum

        init();
        animate();



        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );


            //renderer

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );
            renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            renderer.gammaInput = true;
            renderer.gammaOutput = true;

            //set up the scene

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

            //set up the Orthographic Camera

            camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( - height * aspect, height * aspect, height, - height, 1, 10000 );
            camera.position.z = 1500;
            scene.add( camera );

            //set up the controls

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls.enableZoom = true;
            controls.enableDamping = true;

            //set up the lights

            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x111111 );
            scene.add( ambientLight );

            pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0x030303, 0.5 );
            pointLight.position.z = 2500;
            scene.add( pointLight );

            var pointLight2 = new THREE.PointLight( 0x030303, 1 );
            camera.add( pointLight2 );

            var pointLight3 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xe8e4e4, 0.5 );
            pointLight3.position.x = - 1000;
            pointLight3.position.z = 1000;
            scene.add( pointLight3 );

            //create the environment map

            var imgAr = [
                      'sources/instagram2/image1.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image2.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image3.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image4.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image5.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image6.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image7.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image8.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image9.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image10.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image11.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image12.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image13.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image14.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image15.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image16.jpg'
                    ];

            var urls = imgAr.sort(function(){return .6 - Math.random()}).slice(0,6);
            var reflectionCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls, THREE.CubeReflectionMapping );


            //Load the animation

            var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
            loader.load( "sources/models/animated/horse.js", function ( geometry ) {

                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {

                    morphTargets: true,
                    overdraw: 0.5,
                    envMap: reflectionCube,
                    combine: THREE.AddOperation,
                    reflectivity: 1,
                    shininess: 0,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide                  
                } );

                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                mesh.scale.set( 1.5, 1.5, 1.5 );
                mesh.position.set(0,-150,0);
                scene.add( mesh );

                mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh );

                var clip = THREE.AnimationClip.CreateFromMorphTargetSequence( 'gallop', geometry.morphTargets, 30 );
                mixer.addAction( new THREE.AnimationAction( clip ).warpToDuration( 1 ) );

            } );

            // window resize

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

            function onWindowResize() {

            var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

            camera.left = - height * aspect;
            camera.right = height * aspect;
            camera.top = height;
            camera.bottom = - height;

            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

            //set up the background

            var backgroundMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: texture
            }));

            backgroundMesh .material.depthTest = false;
            backgroundMesh .material.depthWrite = false;


            var backgroundScene = new THREE.Scene();
            var backgroundCamera = new THREE.Camera();
            backgroundScene .add(backgroundCamera );
            backgroundScene .add(backgroundMesh );



        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            controls.update();
            render();

        }

        var radius = 600;
        var theta = 0;

        var prevTime = Date.now();

        function render() {

            theta += 0.1;

            camera.position.x = radius * Math.sin( THREE.Math.degToRad( theta ) );
            camera.position.z = radius * Math.cos( THREE.Math.degToRad( theta ) );

            camera.lookAt( camera.target );

            if ( mixer ) {

                var time = Date.now();

                mixer.update( ( time - prevTime ) * 0.001 );

                prevTime = time;

            }

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
            renderer.render(backgroundScene , backgroundCamera );
            mixer.update();

        }

    </script>nter code here
```

Comment: what is the error? Also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i verify an error? And thank you for your conseil, I am learning.

Comment: If you don't see any error and you feel the code should work... try rotating your camera.. or increasing the size of the object. Because i've faced problems such, that the object is not in visible region of the camera.